# jQuery add or remove table row based on inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorry, if this is too basic.

1. I am trying to add rows to a table if current number of rows are
   less than a user's demand.
2. At the same time, I need to delete the
   extra rows if current number of rows are more than a user's need.

My code is working, but I think it does not make a lot of sense. So I am wondering if anyone could correct my mistakes and make my code more reasonable. (I was trying to use two indices to control this add or remove activity. One index check the current existed elements and get the difference between user's new input. Then do the add or remove movements. But I failed to do this.)

In addition, is it possible to adjust the width of added `<td>` without changing the `shape of the first table row?` Thanks for your help! Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/godhong/322f2/10/).

#### HTML

```
<form method="post" id="form1" action=index.html>
    <table class="tab tab_Application" border="0">
        <tr>
            <th>
                <label for="id_noa">Number of Applications:</label>
            </th>
            <td>
                <select name="noa" id="id_noa">
                    <option value="">Make a selection</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id='noa_header' style="display:none">
            <th>App#</th>
            <th>Month</th>
            <th>Day</th>
            <th>Mass Applied (kg/hA)</th>
            <th>Slow Release (1/day)</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

#### JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var i = 1
    $('#id_noa').change(function () {
        var total = $(this).val()
        $('#noa_header').show()

    //I was trying to use two indices to control this add or remove activity. One index check the current existed elements and get the difference between user's new input. Then do the add or remove movements. But I failed to do this.

        while (i <= total) {
            $('.tab_Application').append('<tr class="tab_noa1"><td><input type="text" size="5" value="' + i + '"/></td><td><input type="text" size="5" name="mm' + i + '" id="id_mm' + i + '""/></td><td><input type="text" size="5" name="dd' + i + '" id="id_dd' + i + '""/></td><td><input type="text" size="5" name="ma' + i + '" id="id_ma' + i + '""/></td><td><input type="text" size="5" name="sr' + i + '" id="id_sr' + i + '" value="0""/></td></tr>');
            i = i + 1;
        }
        while (i-1 > total) {
            $(".tab_Application tr:last").remove();
            i=i-1
        }

        $('</table>').appendTo('.tab_Application');

    })
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took the ideas presented by @B3aT, edited, and fleshed out to make this (available at [my fork of OP's jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amullins/5LkUQ/3/):

```
var row_i = 0;

function emptyRow() {
  row_i++;
  this.obj = $("<tr></tr>");
  this.obj.append('<td><input type="text" size="5" value="' + row_i + '"/></td>');
  this.obj.append('<td><input type="text" size="5" name="mm' + row_i + '" id="id_mm' + row_i + '""/></td>');
  this.obj.append('<td><input type="text" size="5" name="dd' + row_i + '" id="id_dd' + row_i + '""/></td>');
  this.obj.append('<td><input type="text" size="5" name="ma' + row_i + '" id="id_ma' + row_i + '""/></td>');
  this.obj.append('<td><input type="text" size="5" name="sr' + row_i + '" id="id_sr' + row_i + '" value="0""/></td>');
}

function refresh(new_count) {
  if(new_count > 0) {
    $("#noa_header").show();
  }
  else {
    $("#noa_header").hide();
  }
  var old_count = parseInt($('tbody').children().length);

  var rows_difference = parseInt(new_count) - old_count;

  if (rows_difference > 0)
  {
     for(var i = 0; i < rows_difference; i++)
        $('tbody').append((new emptyRow()).obj);
  }
  else if (rows_difference < 0)//we need to remove rows ..
  {
     var index_start = old_count + rows_difference + 1;          
     $('tr:gt('+index_start+')').remove();
     row_i += rows_difference;
  }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#id_noa').change(function () {
        refresh( $(this).val() );
    })
});
```

The reason the `emptyRow` function is so long is that I wanted to make the number of columns easy to manipulate. Each column is appended individually, so changing the default pattern is simple.

In the html, I had to add the `thead` and `tbody` tags as described in @B3aT's answer.  The thead includes the first two rows, because row 1 is the select box and row 2 is the actual header for the table. The tbody is empty to start.

As far as changing styles for individual rows (like adjusting column width), you'd be better off not using a table. Table-like behavior can be as simple as using `float:left` in your column style, making sure to place a div with `clear:both` at the end of each row.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Might I know why you need to separate `thead` and `tbody`? Also, is there a way to define the width of different rows in a table?

Comment: I just did that to implement @B3aT's solution. You could just as easily query for the table rows without it.

Answer (score 2):

At these situations jQuery excels, let us play with all sort of selectors. 
First you need to separate the header and body of the table (thead and tbody).
(Code not tested).

```
function refresh(new_count) {
//how many applications we have drawed now ?
var old_count = parseInt($('tbody').children().count());
//the difference, we need to add or remove ?
var rows_difference = parseInt(new_count) - old_count;
//if we have rows to add
if (rows_difference > 0)
{
    //$('tbody').append() or prepend() new empty rows based on your pattern with a loop
}
else if (rows_difference < 0)//we need to remove rows ..
{
    var index_start = old_count - rows_difference;//for the LAST X rows
    $('tr:gt('+index_start+')').remove();
}
}
```