# js + rails - can't get this form working

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3

I adapted this js from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15130587/jquery-add-or-remove-table-row-based-on-inputs) SO question, but I've never used js before and not sure what I'm doing wrong here.  It's very possible it's a simple fix, but your help is hugely appreciated.

**The goal**:  When a user adds a class, they put in the name, the type, and the number of students.  When `:number_of_students` changes, the js kicks in and shows the appropriate number of forms_for student (the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/5LkUQ/6/) i'm working from).

**The problem**: Overall it's working - the view works, and submitted data goes to the right place.  But the first bit of the header (name of gender labels) show up initially, even though they shouldn't (they're all part of the table with id="nos_header".  When I change the `:number_of_students` however, instead of rows showing up, the header disappears and nothing else appears.

**Where I'm at**:

here's the javascript in `student_groups.js`:

```
    var row_i = 0;

function emptyRow() {
   row_i++;
   this.obj = $("<tr></tr>");
   this.obj.append('<td><input type="text" size="5" value="' + row_i + '"/></td>');
   this.obj.append('<td><input type="text" size="5" name="Student name' + row_i + '"     id="ss_name' + row_i + '""/></td>');
   this.obj.append('<td><input type="text" size="5" name="Gender' + row_i + '" id="ss_gender' + row_i + '""/></td>');
}

function refresh(new_count) {
//how many applications we have drawed now ?
    console.log("New count= " + new_count);
    if(new_count > 0) {
        $('#nos_header').show();
    }
    else {
        $('#nos_header').hide();
    }
var old_count = parseInt($('tbody').children().length);
    console.log("Old count= " + old_count);
//the difference, we need to add or remove ?
var rows_difference = parseInt(new_count) - old_count;
 console.log("Rows diff= " + rows_difference);
//if we have rows to add
if (rows_difference > 0)
  {
    for(var i = 0; i < rows_difference; i++)
    $('tbody').append((new emptyRow()).obj);
  }
else if (rows_difference < 0)//we need to remove rows ..
  {
    var index_start = old_count + rows_difference + 1; 
    console.log("Index start= "+index_start);
    $('tr:gt('+index_start+')').remove();
    row_i += rows_difference;
  }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#nos').change(function () {
        refresh( $(this).val() );
    })
});
```

and `student_groups/new.html.erb` (apologies for the funky formatting, this is how it's best to read in my textmate file):

```
<%= form_for(@student_group) do |f| %>

  <p>
    <span class="form_field"><%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: "The name of this group" %></span>
  is a/an 
    <%= f.select :type_of_group, [["select a group type", ""], "young learners class (0-6)", "primary class (7-12)", "secondary class (13-17)", "adult class (18+)", "children's sport team", "adult's sport team"] %> 
  and there are 
    <span id="nos" class="dropdown"><%= f.select :number_of_students, (0..60) %></span>
  members.
  </p>


  <table id="nos_header">
      <tbody>    
        <tr>
          <td><%= f.label :name, "Student name:" %></td>
              <td><%= f.label :gender, "Gender:" %></td>
        </tr>
      <%= f.fields_for :students do |builder| %>
        <%= render 'students/form', :f => builder %>
      <% end %>
      </tbody>
    </table>

<%= f.submit "Submit", :class => 'big_button round unselectable' %>
```

lastly `students/_form.html.erb`:

```
<tr>
  <td id="ss_name" class="form_field"><%= f.text_field :name %></td>
  <td id="ss_gender" class="dropdown"><%= f.select :gender, ['Female', 'Male', 'Transgender'] %></td>   
</tr>
```

Comment: Your saying that "When I change the :number_of_students however, instead of rows showing up, the header disappears and nothing else appears ", but your fiddle working fine as intended i guess.

Comment: ah sorry, that's not my fiddle, that's the one that i'm using as an example

Comment: oh ok ok cool . can u update your scenario in a fiddle,it will be easier to understand your problem and fix it :)

Comment: **edit**: actually nm, got it!  http://jsfiddle.net/BLwYv/

Comment: Ah, no i dont think so bro. lets do one thing, i can see that your .erb file contains nothing more than basic html elements. so assuming your using html as of now, paste the relevant html code which is needed for the required js functionality, along with your js code in the fiddle. will have look into it :)

Comment: @dreamweiver got it now.  cheers for your help!  jsfiddle.net/BLwYv

Comment: there were few mistakes, i have corrected them.http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/BLwYv/1/. let me know if this is what you wanted ?

Comment: yeah that's pretty close to perfect!  thanks!  2 small questions - why does it pop-up the selected `:number_of_students` (cause i don't want that) and how would i add a class to the new rows (ie: this.obj.append('<td><input type="text" size="5" name="Student name' + row_i + '" id="ss_name' **class="form_field** + row_i + '""/></td>');)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32756/discussion-between-dreamweiver-and-dax)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there were few mistakes , i have corrected it.below is the respective code as well the live working copy from Fiddle.

[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/BLwYv/3/)

**JS CODE:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  //hide table by default
  $('#nos_header').hide ();

  $('#nos').change(function () {
    var opt=$('#nos option:selected');
      //alert(opt.text());
    refresh(opt.text());
  })
});
```

Happy Coding :)