# Jquery add and remove DIV tag row based on select value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found this great stackoverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15130587/jquery-add-or-remove-table-row-based-on-inputs) that does what I need: add and remove rows based on a select value, but the only difference is that in my case, I don't have a table but blocks of divs. In the table example it works fine, but with divs it fails.
I've been using the console to try to fix it to no avail. It seems there are problems with the index value and the increment, but I don't undertand why with a table row works but with divs it doesnot. Could anyone take a look?
Here's a jsfiddle that shows the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/njes3w1a/1/

This is my script:

```
if ($('#returnRequest').length) {

var row_i = 0;

function emptyRow() {
    row_i++;
    this.obj = $('<div class="return-row control-group row"></div>');
    this.obj.append('<div class="col-md-6"><label class="control-label">Serial number</label><input type="text" class="form-control" value=""/></div><div class="col-md-4"><label class="control-label">Item is</label><select class="form-control"><option value="">Select</option><option value="1">New and unopened</option><option value="2">Defective</option></select></div>');
}

function refresh(new_count) {
    //how many applications we have drawed now ?
    console.log("New count= " + new_count);
    if (new_count > 0) {
        $("#noa_header").show();
    } else {
        $("#noa_header").hide();
    }
    var old_count = parseInt($('#productRowWrapper').children().length);
    console.log("Old count= " + old_count);
    //the difference, we need to add or remove ?
    var rows_difference = parseInt(new_count) - old_count;
    console.log("Rows diff= " + rows_difference);
    //if we have rows to add
    if (rows_difference > 0) {
        console.log('enetered a');
        for (var i = 0; i < rows_difference; i++)
        $('#productRowWrapper').append((new emptyRow()).obj);
    } else if (rows_difference < 0) //we need to remove rows ..
    {
        console.log('enetered b');
        var index_start = old_count + rows_difference + 1;
        console.log("Index start= " + index_start);
        $('.return-row:gt(' + index_start + ')').remove();
        console.log(row_i);
        console.log(rows_difference);
        row_i += rows_difference;
        console.log(row_i);
    }
}

$('#quantityReturn').change(function () {
    refresh($(this).val());
});
}
```

Comment: try looping through the array of divs and using .remove() the .remove() will remove whatever item is selected.

Comment: what is not working?? What is the change you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use this code:

```
if ($('#returnRequest').length) {
    function emptyRow() {
        this.obj = $('<div class="return-row control-group row"></div>');
        this.obj.append(
          '<input type="text" class="form-control" value=""/>' +
          '<select class="form-control">' +
              '<option value="">Select</option>' +
              '<option value="1">New and unopened</option>' +
              '<option value="2">Defective</option>' +
          '</select>');
    }

    function refresh(count) {
        if (count > 0) {
            $("#noa_header").show();
        } else {
            $("#noa_header").hide();
        }

        var wrapper = $('#productRowWrapper');

        while (wrapper.children().length > count)
            wrapper.children().last().remove();

        while (wrapper.children().length < count)
            wrapper.append((new emptyRow()).obj);
    }

    $('#quantityReturn').change(function () {
        refresh(parseInt($(this).val()));
    });
}
```

It does not introduce unnecessary variables and it a bit shorter. Updated fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/njes3w1a/6/.

Comment: It's working ok finally. I will review your logic and if I have questions, I hopeyou can give me some answer. Thanks

Comment: No problems. You can add comments here then.

Comment: Why this got downvote? BTW, you can shorten/cache it even further http://jsfiddle.net/wzevjkb2/ :)

Answer (score 0):

you were calculating your strt index wrong add this

```
 var index_start =old_count- Math.abs(rows_difference)-1 ;
```

---

***Code***

```js
 if ($('#returnRequest').length) {

     var row_i = 0;

     function emptyRow() {
         row_i++;
         this.obj = $('<div class="return-row control-group row"></div>');
         this.obj.append('<input type="text" class="form-control" value=""/><select class="form-control"><option value="">Select</option><option value="1">New and unopened</option><option value="2">Defective</option></select>');
     }

     function refresh(new_count) {
         //how many applications we have drawed now ?
         console.log("New count= " + new_count);
         if (new_count > 0) {
             $("#noa_header").show();
         } else {
             $("#noa_header").hide();
         }
         var old_count = parseInt($('#productRowWrapper').children().length);
         console.log("Old count= " + old_count);
         //the difference, we need to add or remove ?
         var rows_difference = parseInt(new_count) - old_count;
         console.log("Rows diff= " + rows_difference);
         //if we have rows to add
         if (rows_difference > 0) {
             console.log('enetered a');
             for (var i = 0; i < rows_difference; i++)
             $('#productRowWrapper').append((new emptyRow()).obj);
         } else if (rows_difference < 0) //we need to remove rows ..
         {
             console.log('enetered b');
             var index_start =old_count- Math.abs(rows_difference)-1 ;
             console.log("Index start= " + index_start);
               console.log('.return-row:gt(' + index_start + ')');
             $('.return-row:gt(' + index_start + ')').remove();
             console.log(row_i);
             console.log(rows_difference);
             row_i += rows_difference;
             console.log(row_i);
         }
     }

     $('#quantityReturn').change(function () {
         refresh($(this).val());
     });
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="" id="returnRequest">
    <div class="form-group row">
        <p class="col-sm-3 control-label">* Quantity to return</p>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <div class="row control-group">
                <div class="col-sm-6 control-item" id="signupForename">
                    <select class="form-control" id="quantityReturn">
                        <option value="0">Please select</option>
                        <option value="1">1 item</option>
                        <option value="2">2 items</option>
                        <option value="3">3 items</option>
                        <option value="4">4 items</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="pane-body">
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <div id="noa_header" style="display: none;">Header</div>
                    <div id="productRowWrapper"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When I select the "Please select" option, I still see the first row.